# Background push notifications sent through Parse are not delivered

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I’m trying to send “background push” (`content-available`) notifications to an iOS device. The receiving code works fine, as verified by the [Houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) command-line utility. I can also send regular push notifications just fine through Parse. But as soon as I add the `content-available` key (setting it to `@YES`), the push notifications are never delivered. Trying with different `alert` and `sound` values does not change anything. When I look into the Parse web “console” under the Push Notifications tab, the “Subscribers” value for these undelivered notifications is zero. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `"content-available`" to `@"1"` instead of `@yes`

For example, my working code:

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"", @"alert",
                          @"1", @"content-available",
                          nil];
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:someQuery];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: `@1` also works, but `@YES` doesn’t. Looks like there’s some kind of payload validation somewhere along the way that doesn’t like a bool value for the `content-available` field. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! :) content-available MUST be a NUMBER, "Provide this key with a value of 1 to indicate that new content is available" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not registering to the correct notification types.

Try :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability];
```

Comment: As I said, the receiving code works, I receive the notifications sent by other means.